# how to give placeholder for ngx-treeview. Is there any property?

Tags: angular

By default, ngx-treeview has placeholder text called 'filter'. I want to change this default placeholder to other text. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any chances of displaying custom placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, change it on the compoenent level.

```
import { TreeviewItem, TreeviewConfig, TreeviewI18nDefault , TreeviewI18n } from 'ngx-treeview';
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [
      {
         provide: TreeviewI18n , useValue: Object.assign(new TreeviewI18nDefault(), {
           getFilterPlaceholder(): string {
             return 'my custom Filter';
           }

           // also override other methods if needed
           // getText(selection: TreeviewSelection): string;
           // getAllCheckboxText(): string;
           // getFilterPlaceholder(): string;
           // getFilterNoItemsFoundText(): string;
           // getTooltipCollapseExpandText(isCollapse: boolean): string;
        })
      }
 ],
 })
 export class MyComponent  {
    constructor(    private treeviewI18nDefault: TreeviewI18n   ) {   }
 }
```