# How to change placeholder in ngx-treeview

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-treeview

How can we change the placeholder of treeview, using an appropriate method

```
providers: [
 {
   provide: TreeviewI18n, useValue: Object.assign(new TreeviewI18nDefault(),{
    getFilterPlaceholder(): string {
       return ' search Library ...';
    }
  })
 }
]
```

With the above method, I am achieving the same but seems it's breaking up in production time, I mean if there is any better way to change the placeholder text

[image]

Comment: The library has been in a way that you can use TreeviewI18nDefault class to implement localization. What you can do is fork the library and make changes. e.g. create input for component for placeholder and use something like this [placeholder]="placeholder || i18n.getFilterPlaceholder()"

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: @Jaihind    No Luck!

Comment: @Jaihind here you are, I answered this question

Answer (score 3):

actually ngx-treeview rename TreeviewI18nDefault() class to DefaultTreeviewI18n()
you can change this class and use it to change placeholders

you can use this code on your shared module or component

```
import {
    DefaultTreeviewI18n, DropdownTreeviewComponent, TreeviewI18n, TreeviewModule,
} from 'ngx-treeview';



providers: [
    DropdownTreeviewComponent,
    {
        provide: TreeviewI18n, useValue: Object.assign(new DefaultTreeviewI18n(), {
            getFilterPlaceholder(): string {
                return 'your custom placeholder';
            },
            getAllCheckboxText(): string {
                return 'your custom placeholder';
            },
            getFilterNoItemsFoundText(): string {
                return 'your custom placeholder';
            },
        }),
    }
]
```

you can use some other method if you want ,
there is a list of other methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657979/11094486)

Comment: and how to use it in .html or .ts ? Can you give an example?

Comment: @RouhollahTorshizi actually you don't need to do anything in your component                              `<ngx-dropdown-treeview #treeviewComponent (filterChange)="onFilterChange($event)"
                                                           (selectedChange)="addToForm(values = $event)" [config]="config"
                                                           [items]="items" buttonClass="btn-outline-secondary"
                                                           id="ID">
                                    </ngx-dropdown-treeview>` its on .html file

Comment: @RouhollahTorshizi  its on .ts file  `treeViewConfig: TreeviewConfig.create({
        hasAllCheckBox: true,
        hasFilter: true,
        hasCollapseExpand: true,
        decoupleChildFromParent: false,
        maxHeight: 400
    })`   just it